# Assigning variables from elements of a data frame

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that, for each row, I would like to create a variable from the variable name part and assign it the corresponding value, so that I will end up with three variables (variable1 <- "c" etc)

```
d <- data.frame(
  variable_name = c("variable1", "variable2", "variable3"), 
  variable_value = c("c", "a", "b")
)
```

Currently the only way I can think to approach this is by manually listing each row that I would like to take out

```
variable1 <- subset(d,variable_name == "variable1")[1,2]
variable2 <- subset(d,variable_name == "variable2")[1,2]
variable3 <- subset(d,variable_name == "variable3")[1,2]
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: So you basically want a vectorized version of `assign`. (Ick.)

Comment: @Sam Gilbert May be you can use `list2env` after creating a `list` object

Comment: Thanks for quick replies, both using assign and list2env worked thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 list2env(setNames(as.list(as.character(d$variable_value)),
                                 d$variable_name), envir=.GlobalEnv)

  variable1
  #[1] c

  variable2
  #[1] "a"
```